# In Box2D, how to set the sleepTime of an object?

Tags: javascript, box2d, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm working on a educational physics project and I've chosen Box2D as my main engine for a "Build your own rocket" like physics game.

Box2D looks very intuitive and the documentation seems pretty good IMMO, but I **couldn't find how to set the sleeping time of a given body**. Is it possible?

I've already tried the lazy approach:

```
var newB = new b2BodyDef();
    newB.m_sleepTime = 12000;
```

Unfortunately, the `newB` still starts to sleep almost instantaneously after it gets into a rest position.

Comment: lol the most helpful comment ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SetSleepingAllowed(bool) on an individual body, or set the entire world to not sleep when you create it. Unless you have a huge number of bodies in your simulation, I would just use one of these and keep the body awake all the time. You can also SetAwake(bool) on individual bodies if you know when you'll need them to be awake.

Comment: I'm just wondering why there is a sleepTime property if it has no effect.

Comment: Looking at the source just now I see you are right. But that property seems to be only used by the internals of the engine and not for us to mess around with :)